# Showing Modal as normal div - Reactstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

I have a Reactstrap Modal: [Modal - Reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/modals/)

I would like to use this modal as a I would use a "normal" div in a page layout.

I.E. Show the modal inside the page with the same design, just without it popping in and out, and blurring the rest of the page.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @Colin his code is irrelevant. The question is clear.

Comment: Not really. If he posted code I could show how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to modify or override the CSS files of Reactstrap to achieve that. But it would not be a Modal any longer. It is better if you ask about what you want to achieve. You don't need to use modals to show a div with a toggle button.

Comment: I want a div that looks exactly like a modal.
For example, a login modal that pops and a login page that looks the same.